# POST JSON CURL Command to PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm executing below query in command line and get results

```
curl -k --header "Authorization: Bearer fc68946e-6b31-45ba-9006-d3519a9e1464" -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{'reportName':'Aggregation/Archive Log','indexFrom':'1','reportParameter': {'QUERY_FROM_DATE':'NOW -30 MONTH','QUERY_TO_DATE':'NOW','SQLGuardHostName':'%','SHOW_ALIASES':'TRUE','REMOTE_SOURCE':'%'}}" https://10.10.9.239:8443/restAPI/online_report
```

I want to execute this command with php.

Can you please help me to generate php code?

```
<?php
$url = "https://10.10.9.239:8443/restAPI/online_report";
$data_json = "{'reportName':'Aggregation/Archive Log','indexFrom':'1','reportParameter': {'QUERY_FROM_DATE':'NOW -30 MONTH','QUERY_TO_DATE':'NOW','SQLGuardHostName':'%','SHOW_ALIASES':'TRUE','REMOTE_SOURCE':'%'}}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: You need to do some proper research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues with your existing code, but we're not here to write it all for you (which a proper answer to this question would require us to do.)

Comment: Hi Magnus, I found some codes but I couldn't add -k --header "Authorization: Bearer fc68946e-6b31-45ba-9006-d3519a9e1464" part of this command.

Comment: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/